# The issue with starting JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final server(eclipse)

Tags: java, netbeans

Good day.

I am trying to start jboss as 7.1.1 final server(eclipse).

I installed JBoss tools, downloaded JBoss Application Server (AS), extracted zip file, opened eclipse and added server. Then, I configured server, started it.

Console output is:

```
12:39:13,338 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
12:39:13,720 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
12:39:13,781 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
```

Then I typed

```
> http://localhost:8080
```

in browser and shouldn't able to see the JBoss AS Welcome screen. I saw "This webpage is not available".

Have someone already have the same situation?

Comment: Is `8080` the correct port?

Comment: I went to Servers tab and there for the "xml configuration - ports - jboss web" property value is 8080

Comment: If I remember correctly the JBoss AS mentions the listened ports during the startup process. If you have access to that log, then check that as well. And also try `http://127.0.0.1:8080`.

Comment: I checked log file for a standalone server in the log subdirectory(./standalone/log/boot.log). There are configured system properties and no 'port' property in the file.